# How do fix automatic redirect /* when I get a paymentIntent url from stripe

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

This error only occurs when my application is deployed.

After the user inputs their card information, and clicks `pay` a payment intent is created, and I return the user the paymentStatus component:

```
  const { error }: any = await stripe.confirmPayment({
      elements,
      confirmParams: {
        return_url: `${currentUrl}/paymentstatus`,
      },
    });
```

In the payment status, if the payment is successful, a success page will show up.

the issue is that the above return URL adds on it the payment_intent and it's status so the URL ends up looking something like this:

```
https://mywebsiteURL/paymentstatus?payment_intent=...success=true
```

The problem with this is that in my render.com default redirects, I have a `/*=/` meaning if I visit any route that doesn't exist I get redirected to the home page, and though the /paymentStatus route does exist in my app router, this still gets redirected to the home page because of the added ?payment_intent.....

How do I go about fixing this? if I remove the default redirects in my render.com I'll get `page does not exist` and a `404` error when I make the payment. Also, why does this work in fine my localhost?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your web server's routing setting to allow it accept query parameters. If you can't figure it out, a workaround would be setting [redirect](https://docs.stripe.com/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment#confirm_payment_intent-options-redirect) to `if_required` to prevent redirections if you only accept non-redirect based payment methods (i.e., card payments).